# Problem with Friends of Tracking Code NOOB [PYTHON]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning with python code and I have some issues:

https://github.com/Slothfulwave612/Football-Analytics-Using-Python/blob/master/03.%20Analyzing%20Event%20Data/pass_map.py

My dubt is really simple:

I would like to apply a for expresion in order to apply the pass code to multiple football matches.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import json
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    from FCPython import createPitch
```

```
pitch_length_X = 120
pitch_width_Y = 80

(fig,ax) = createPitch(pitch_length_X, pitch_width_Y,'yards','gray')

## the code integrated in order to analyze multiple matches
P1TMP = [16205, 16131, 16265]
for i in P1TMP:

  ## match id for our El Clasico
  match_id = int(i)

  home_team = 'Barcelona'
  player_name = 'Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini'

  ## this is the name of our event data file for
  ## our required El Clasico
  file_name = str(match_id) + '.json'

  ## loading the required event data file
  my_data = json.load(open('/content/drive/My Drive/20200515 CHIRINGUITO/events/' + file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8'))

  ## get the nested structure into a dataframe 
  ## store the dataframe in a dictionary with the match id as key
  df = json_normalize(my_data, sep='_').assign(match_id = file_name[:-5])


  ## making the list of all column names
  column = list(df.columns)

  ## all the type names we have in our dataframe
  all_type_name = list(df['type_name'].unique())

  ## creating a data frame for pass
  ## and then removing the null values
  ## only listing the player_name in the dataframe
  pass_df = df.loc[df['type_name'] == 'Pass', :].copy()
  pass_df.dropna(inplace=True, axis=1)
  pass_df = pass_df.loc[pass_df['player_name'] == player_name, :]
  ## creating a data frame for ball receipt
  ## removing all the null values
  ## and only listing Barcelona players in the dataframe
  breceipt_df = df.loc[df['type_name'] == 'Ball Receipt*', :].copy()
  breceipt_df.dropna(inplace=True, axis=1)
  breceipt_df = breceipt_df.loc[breceipt_df['team_name'] == 'Barcelona', :]
  pass_comp, pass_no = 0, 0
  ## pass_comp: completed pass
  ## pass_no: unsuccessful pass



  ## iterating through the pass dataframe
  for row_num, passed in pass_df.iterrows():   
      if passed['player_name'] == player_name:  
        ## for away side
        x_loc = passed['location'][0]
        y_loc = passed['location'][1]

        pass_id = passed['id']
        summed_result = sum(breceipt_df.iloc[:, 14].apply(lambda x: pass_id in x))
        if summed_result > 0:
        ## if pass made was successful
           color = 'blue'
           label = 'Successful'
           pass_comp += 1
        else:
          ## if pass made was unsuccessful
          color = 'green'
          label = 'Unsuccessful'
          pass_no += 1

        ## plotting circle at the player's position
        shot_circle = plt.Circle((pitch_length_X - x_loc, y_loc), radius=2, color=color, label=label)
        shot_circle.set_alpha(alpha=0.2)
        ax.add_patch(shot_circle)

        ## parameters for making the arrow
        pass_x = 120 - passed['pass_end_location'][0]
        pass_y = passed['pass_end_location'][1] 
        dx = ((pitch_length_X - x_loc) - pass_x)
        dy = y_loc - pass_y

        ## making an arrow to display the pass
        pass_arrow = plt.Arrow(pitch_length_X - x_loc, y_loc, -dx, -dy, width=1, color=color)

        ## adding arrow to the plot
        ax.add_patch(pass_arrow)
```

## computing pass accuracy
    pass_acc = (pass_comp / (pass_comp + pass_no)) * 100
    pass_acc = str(round(pass_acc, 2))

    ## adding text to the plot
    plt.text(20, 85, '{} pass map vs Real Madrid'.format(player_name), fontsize=15)
    plt.text(20, 82, 'Pass Accuracy: {}'.format(pass_acc), fontsize=15)

    ## handling labels
    handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
    by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
    plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 1, 0, 0),fontsize=12)

    ## editing the figure size and saving it
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 8)
    fig.savefig('{} passmap.png'.format(match_id), dpi=200)

    ## showing the plot
    plt.show()

**I only have edited the code in order to analayze multiple matches with a for expresion.**

P1TMP = [16205, 16131, 16265]
for i in P1TMP:

And the results:

**In The first image the result is almost perfect, but the Kind of passes´s filter is not working.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zldhF.png)

**In the second image the passes are a mix of the passes of the first match and the second match. I only want the passes of the second match.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sslPs.png)

And in the third is the mix of the match nº1 +nº2 + n3º. I need the passes of the third :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vINZX.png)

Thanks in advance for your support.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's combining all the matches onto 1 because the figure is "drawing" on top of the previous one. There's a few other things you need to change too.

1. The away team will not always be Real Madrid, so make that dynamic
2. Adjust that in the figure text text so it's not always "`vs. Real Madrid"`
3. Save the file as something dynamic so they don't overwrite
4. Instead of doing `plt.text` to put in the titles (which is fine if you want to annotate at a specific x,y coordinates), use `plt.title()` and `plt.suptitle()`. It'll center and just make it a nicer layout of the text
5. You us `i` for you match id variable when iterating, but then you don't change/include that in the loop
6. This is the main issue: `(fig,ax) = createPitch(pitch_length_X, pitch_width_Y,'yards','gray')`
    is what is creating your "blank canvas" to plot on. So this needs to be called before each plot. It's like grabbing a new blank sheet of paper to draw on. If you just use the first initial sheet, then everything will go on that 1 sheet. So move that into your for loop

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from FCPython import createPitch

## Note Statsbomb data uses yards for their pitch dimensions
pitch_length_X = 120
pitch_width_Y = 80



## match id for our El Clasico
match_list = [16205, 16131, 16265]
teamA = 'Barcelona'  #<--- adjusted here

for match_id in match_list:
    ## calling the function to create a pitch map
    ## yards is the unit for measurement and
    ## gray will be the line color of the pitch map
    (fig,ax) = createPitch(pitch_length_X, pitch_width_Y,'yards','gray') #< moved into for loop

    player_name = 'Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini'

    ## this is the name of our event data file for
    ## our required El Clasico
    file_name = str(match_id) + '.json'

    ## loading the required event data file
    my_data = json.load(open('Statsbomb/data/events/' + file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8'))


    ## get the nested structure into a dataframe 
    ## store the dataframe in a dictionary with the match id as key
    df = json_normalize(my_data, sep='_').assign(match_id = file_name[:-5])
    teamB = [x for x in list(df['team_name'].unique()) if x != teamA ][0] #<--- get other team name

    ## making the list of all column names
    column = list(df.columns)

    ## all the type names we have in our dataframe
    all_type_name = list(df['type_name'].unique())

    ## creating a data frame for pass
    ## and then removing the null values
    ## only listing the player_name in the dataframe
    pass_df = df.loc[df['type_name'] == 'Pass', :].copy()
    pass_df.dropna(inplace=True, axis=1)
    pass_df = pass_df.loc[pass_df['player_name'] == player_name, :]

    ## creating a data frame for ball receipt
    ## removing all the null values
    ## and only listing Barcelona players in the dataframe
    breceipt_df = df.loc[df['type_name'] == 'Ball Receipt*', :].copy()
    breceipt_df.dropna(inplace=True, axis=1)
    breceipt_df = breceipt_df.loc[breceipt_df['team_name'] == 'Barcelona', :]

    pass_comp, pass_no = 0, 0
    ## pass_comp: completed pass
    ## pass_no: unsuccessful pass

    ## iterating through the pass dataframe
    for row_num, passed in pass_df.iterrows():   

        if passed['player_name'] == player_name:
            ## for away side
            x_loc = passed['location'][0]
            y_loc = passed['location'][1]

            pass_id = passed['id']
            summed_result = sum(breceipt_df.iloc[:, 14].apply(lambda x: pass_id in x))

            if summed_result > 0:
                ## if pass made was successful
                color = 'blue'
                label = 'Successful'
                pass_comp += 1
            else:
                ## if pass made was unsuccessful
                color = 'red'
                label = 'Unsuccessful'
                pass_no += 1

            ## plotting circle at the player's position
            shot_circle = plt.Circle((pitch_length_X - x_loc, y_loc), radius=2, color=color, label=label)
            shot_circle.set_alpha(alpha=0.2)
            ax.add_patch(shot_circle)

            ## parameters for making the arrow
            pass_x = 120 - passed['pass_end_location'][0]
            pass_y = passed['pass_end_location'][1] 
            dx = ((pitch_length_X - x_loc) - pass_x)
            dy = y_loc - pass_y

            ## making an arrow to display the pass
            pass_arrow = plt.Arrow(pitch_length_X - x_loc, y_loc, -dx, -dy, width=1, color=color)

            ## adding arrow to the plot
            ax.add_patch(pass_arrow)

    ## computing pass accuracy
    pass_acc = (pass_comp / (pass_comp + pass_no)) * 100
    pass_acc = str(round(pass_acc, 2))

    ## adding text to the plot
    plt.suptitle('{} pass map vs {}'.format(player_name, teamB), fontsize=15) #<-- make dynamic and change to suptitle
    plt.title('Pass Accuracy: {}'.format(pass_acc), fontsize=15) #<-- change to title

    ## handling labels
    handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
    by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
    plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 1, 0, 0), fontsize=12)

    ## editing the figure size and saving it
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 8)
    fig.savefig('{} passmap.png'.format(match_id), dpi=200)  #<-- dynamic file name

    ## showing the plot
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I can not give you points because I am in the level 0. But I really apreciatte your support.  I have another dubt here:             summed_result = sum(breceipt_df.iloc[:, 14].apply(lambda x: pass_id in x))  in the code it´s not working, at least in collaboratory.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciatte you effort and your help. Please  find attached the problem with the votes : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. If i improve I will retourn to vote you.